# Create a table in powerpoint with Apache poi

Tags: apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm using Java v8 and "org.apache.poi" and "poi-ooxml" (both are version 3.9). I'm trying to create a powerpoint with a slide on it which contains a table.

I can get the powerpoint file to create ok but the slide is empty but for a small black box in the top right corner. I'm guessing I'm missing something small but can't see what it is. I've tried some examples from the web and they look to be the same as what I'm seeing.

This is what I see in the Powerpoint slide:

[image]

My code is as below:

```
    XMLSlideShow powerpoint = new XMLSlideShow();
    XSLFSlide slide = powerpoint.createSlide();

    XSLFTable table = slide.createTable();
    table.setAnchor(new Rectangle(50, 50, 800, 800));

    int numColumns = 3;
    int numRows = 5;
    XSLFTableRow headerRow = table.addRow();
    headerRow.setHeight(50);
    // header
    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        XSLFTableCell th = headerRow.addCell();
        XSLFTextParagraph p = th.addNewTextParagraph();
        p.setTextAlign(TextAlign.CENTER);
        XSLFTextRun r = p.addNewTextRun();
        r.setText("Header " + (i + 1));
        r.setFontSize(20);
        r.setFontColor(Color.white);
        th.setFillColor(new Color(79, 129, 189));
        table.setColumnWidth(i, 150);
    }

    // rows
    for (int rownum = 0; rownum < numRows; rownum++) {
        XSLFTableRow tr = table.addRow();
        tr.setHeight(50);
        // header
        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            XSLFTableCell cell = tr.addCell();
            XSLFTextParagraph p = cell.addNewTextParagraph();
            XSLFTextRun r = p.addNewTextRun();

            r.setText("Cell " + (i + 1));
            if (rownum % 2 == 0) {
                cell.setFillColor(new Color(208, 216, 232));
            }
            else {
                cell.setFillColor(new Color(233, 247, 244));
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\myFile.pptx")) 
         {
            try {
                powerpoint.write(out);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any thoughts/guidance would be really appreciated.

Thanks Ro

Comment: Update on this - when I just now changed my pom.xml to use version 3.17 (and not 3.9) then I can get it working - and I see my table create. Guessing there have been lots of API change between the two versions. I'd ideally like to be on the most stable version (and to find an example of creating a table on that). Thanks Ronan.

Comment: 3.17 is the latest stable release - I'm always puzzled why people use 3.9 and wonder about missing functionality. [The latest poi artifacts search](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.poi%22) points automatically to 3.17, so how come you've chosen 3.9? (this is just such a common mistake and I just try to understand)
Sorry for orphaning the website docu, but you can find examples about the usage in the [tests](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/sl/TestTable.java?view=markup) - here with using the common super interfaces